# Plot When y axis data very small

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I use  `NDSolve` solve the motion equation of a dynamic system. and When I plot the energy of the dynamic system, I find the y axis data is very small, I have take some suggestions like set `AxesOrigin->{Automatic,{0,144}}`,and `PlotRange -> {Automatic, {144 - 1*^-9, 144 + 1*^-9}}`, the result is still like the follows figure:

[image]

I have output the data, the all y axis data(energy) is `144.`, What is the problem with the data, do I need set `NDSolve` `Precision`?

Any advice will be very appreciate!

Thank you!

The NDSolve code is

```
ClearAll
j = DiagonalMatrix[{4, 2, 10}];
d = 1;
\[CapitalGamma] = j + d IdentityMatrix[3];
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 
     Inverse[\[CapitalGamma]].((\[CapitalGamma].x[t])\[Cross]x[t] + 
        d/(1 - d*Dot[rrr[t], Inverse[\[CapitalGamma]].rrr[t]])*
         Dot[Inverse[\[CapitalGamma]].rrr[
            t], (\[CapitalGamma].x[t])\[Cross]x[t]]*rrr[t]),
    r'[t] == r[t]\[Cross]x[t],
    rr'[t] == rr[t]\[Cross]x[t],
    rrr'[t] == rrr[t]\[Cross]x[t],
    p'[t] == -{r[t], rr[t], 
        rrr[t]}.(
         x[t]\[Cross]rrr[
           t]),                                                                                                
    x[0] == {4, 4, 4},
    rrr[0] == {0, 0, 1}, r[0] == {1, 0, 0}, rr[0] == {0, 1, 0},
    p[0] == {0, 0, 0}},
   {x, r, rr, rrr, p}, {t, 0, 2.5}, StartingStepSize -> 5*^-3];
```

The plot code as follows

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  1/2 x[t].\[CapitalGamma].x[t] - 1/2 d*(x[t].rrr[t])*rrr[t].x[t] /. 
   sol], {t, 0, 2.5}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {144 - 1*^-9, 144 + 1*^-9}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run (on Mathematica v12.2)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thank you, I have run it on MMA 12.1, I did't know why it can't run in version 12(.2), Maybe should ClearAll before run the code? I'm new hand..

Comment: `\[Rho]` isn't defined!

Comment: `NDSolve` need's the value of `\[Rho]` to work.  Please modify your question!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, Thank you, I have revised the code!

Answer (score 2):

Your `PlotRange` is very small ( `O[10^-9]` )! What do you expect?

Increase plotrange slightly gives

```
    Plot[Evaluate[
  1/2 x[t] . \[CapitalGamma] . x[t] - 
    1/2 d*(x[t] . rrr[t])*rrr[t] . x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 2.5}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {144 - .001, 144 +  .001}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image]

Now the plot indicates the accuracy of `sol`

Comment: I think the y axis Ticks didn't right, can I make the Ticks more accurate, I have try 'Ticks->{{0,3},{144 - 1*^-4, 144 + 6*^-5}}', but failed, the y axis Tick is still not change

Comment: @See my modified answer.

Comment: Thank you, can I make the x-y curve more suitable(Zoom in) for the plot window? seems like y-data more heigh and  changes clearly.

Comment: I have set `PlotRange -> {Automatic, {144 - 1.2*^-4, 144 + 0.5*^-4}}`, the plot is more clear, but the Ticks is lost, Can I use Ticks set  *^-4 in y direction?

Comment: Plot the difference `sol-144`: `Plot[Evaluate[
  1/2 x[t] . \[CapitalGamma] . x[t] - 
    1/2 d*(x[t] . rrr[t])*rrr[t] . x[t] - 144 /. sol], {t, 0, 2.5}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {  -.0001,  +.0001}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific"] `

Comment: Good idea, Thank you, by the way, can I reduce the Plot point, let the plot Not so dense? I think `NDSolve`'s result maybe not support set new step to `Plot`?

Comment: Try `PlotPoints->10`

Comment: Thank you, `PlotPoints` option did't work, because result is `InterpolatingFunction` from `NDSolve`

Comment: I'am wrong, `PlotPoints->10` is ok, I have Take it for granted, `10` is not means only `10` point in the plot. I have try `500`, Plot not change.